# How would I access this information via Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

How would I find the value for example *context* with beautifulsoup?

This is what some of what I get when I print my Beautiful var in Python.

```
<script>
(function (root) {
root['__playIT'] = {"context":{"dispatcher":{"stores"} 
}(this));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `BeautifulSoup`, you can only locate the desired `script` element. Then, to extract the actual `context` value, you can use, for example, regular expressions:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<script>
(function (root) {
root['__playIT'] = {"context":{"dispatcher":{"stores"}
}(this));
</script>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

pattern = re.compile(r'"context":(\{.*?)$', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

result = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
{"dispatcher":{"stores"}
```

Note that, if the value would have been the valid JSON string, you could have loaded it with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the fast answer!

When I try to run your code is get this error message:

result = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @gel well, that's one of the reasons I've provided a complete code of what I've been executing. I think your actual script value differs from what you've posted in the question..

Comment: it was your complete code I tried to execute. I did not change anything.

EDIT: If this helps: https://codeshare.io/noIKd

Comment: @gel interesting! What version of Python and BeautifulSoup are you running this on? Thanks.

Comment: I'm using bs4 and Python 2.7.10.